# Include a module and access a class'es constant

Tags: ruby

I have a module which is **included** in a class:

```
module MyModule
  def module_method
    a = @var1 # ok
    #... working with @var1

    # now I need to access MY_CONST of a class it's included into
    p "hello from MyModule " + MY_CONST # error!
  end
end

class MyClass1
  include MyModule
  MY_CONST = "my const1"

  def instance_method1
    @var1 = "some var1"
  end
end

class MyClass2
  include MyModule
  MY_CONST = "my const2"

  def instance_method2
    @var1 = "some var2"
  end
end

a = MyClass1.new
a.instance_method1
a.module_method # error
```

Note that it must be included, not extended by a class. I want to access to a class constant `MyClass1::MY_CONST` and `MyClass2::MY_CONST` from the module(without knowing the name of a class, of course). Can I do this?

Comment: I think you can do this with `self.class::MY_CONST`

Comment: @BroiSatse, is it possible to include a module but made some of the method "static" (class) methods?

Comment: yes it is. I'll post an answer to this in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use it in the instance method you can use `self.class::My_CONST`.

As to your second question, you can add class methods with included module with:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(mod)
    mod.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def class_method
      'foo'
    end
  end
end

class A
  include MyModule
end

A.class_method   #=> "foo"
```